# VB: How can I make buttons over a picture box transparent?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, picturebox, transparent

in my program I have a picture box with a specific width x and height y. Then the user can enter an elementsize (e.g. 10) and then the programm will create buttons with the width and height of the elementsize over the picture box. The thing is that these buttons need to be transparent so only their border is visible. That means that through the buttons you can see the content of the picture box.

So this is my code for creating these buttons when I click on my start button:

```
Imports System.Math
Public Class Form1
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double
Dim elsize As Integer
Dim numberofbuttons As Integer


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    x = 400
    y = 200
    elsize = 20

    numberofbuttons = Round(x / elsize) * Round(y / elsize)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 1 To Round(y / elsize)
        For i = 1 To Round(x / elsize)
            Dim Btn As New Button
            Btn.Width = elsize
            Btn.Height = elsize
            Btn.Location = New Point(elsize * (i - 1), elsize * (j - 1))
            Btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            PictureBox1.Controls.Add(Btn)

        Next
    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

I use

```
Btn.BringToFront()
```

to put these buttons in front of the picture box and I wanted to use

```
Btn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Transparent
```

to make them transparent but this won't work. Has anybody any ideas how to do this? Also I wanted to put these buttons in the coordinate system of the picture box and not of the form1. I thought that this is possible through

```
Btn.Parent = PictureBox1
```

but the buttons always use the coordinate system of the form.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Me.Controls.Add(Btn)
```

is setting the `Parent` of the `Button` to be the form.  You don't `Add` to one parent and assign a different parent explicitly.  Do one or the other.  In short, get rid of that `Add` call and you should be good to go.  Alternatively, get rid of the `Parent` assignmnent and `Add` to the `Controls` collection of the `PictureBox` instead.  I'd suggest the latter.

Either way, DO NOT display the `Button` until you have configured it, i.e. set the `Parent` or call `Controls.Add` last.

EDIT: I tested this code and it worked as expected:

```
Dim btn As New Button

With btn
    .Size = mySize
    .Location = myLocation
    .BackColor = Color.Transparent
    .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat

    PictureBox1.Controls.Add(btn)
End With
```

Comment: Well I know that the question is confusing a bit, but the question is _How can I make buttons over a picture box transparent?_

Comment: You already know that you need to add the `Button` to the `PictureBox` but you're not doing that. I told you what you're doing wrong.  Did you even read my answer?  I'm sure you didn't bother to try what I suggested.  You're wasting my time.

Comment: Hey jmcilhinney, the guy who commented first is not me (the one who created the topic). I'll try your answer. Thanks!

Comment: So my code inside the For-Loop is
                Btn.Width = elsize
                Btn.Height = elsize
                Btn.Location = New Point(elsize * (i - 1), elsize * (j - 1))
                Btn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Transparent
                PictureBox1.Controls.Add(Btn)

Now the buttons are oriented through the picture box but they still are not transparent. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you changed the `FlatStyle`? If not then the appearance of a `Button` will be based on the OS theme. All the options look very similar on Windows 10 and probably Windows 8 too.  It's on Windows 7 and earlier, where controls were more 3D, that you'll see a big difference.

Comment: I have added these lines of code:     Btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
                    Btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1    . But they are still not transparent, so I cannot see through them. I really don't know why the Btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent doesn't make the button transparent.

Comment: In my testing, `Flat` and `Popup` both worked. In the case of `Flat`, the transparency was not maintained while the mouse pointer was over the `Button`. You do know why simply setting the `BackColor` to `Transparent` doesn't work because I told you why. The fact that you think it should work doesn't really count. I just tested the code in the edit above and it worked as expected. If it's not working for you then I think you must be doing something wrong, so maybe you should edit your question and show us your current code.

Comment: Ok, so I edited the code in my post. It is almost the same as yours (only that I don't use "With" and "End With" and inserted some variables for the position). The button turns into the color of the picturebox but if I draw a line in the picture box first and then create the buttons I still cannot see that line.

Comment: So I searched a bit deeper online and found the following opinion: True transparency does not exist in VB. If you set the button transparent its color will be the color of its parent. But if its parent contains something like a drawn line, then you won't see this line.
Can you confirm this? @jmcilhinney

Comment: So I have two new solutions for this problem if the "true transparency" does really not exist:
1. Don't use buttons. Instead make clickable areas on the picturebox. But this would be a bit complicated because I would have to draw the borders of these clickable areas manually
2. Make picture of the recent picturebox content and then set the background of each button to its belonging part of this picture.
(http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?457826-transparent-button-over-a-picturebox)
What do you think of these methods?

Comment: This has nothing to do with VB. As I told you some time ago, controls are not genuinely transparent in Windows Forms. That's true of both C# and C++ as well as VB. The language is irrelevant. Likewise, controls can be genuinely transparent in WPF regardless of the language, because WPF was designed that way from the ground up. If you want a line to appear over a `PictureBox` and a `Button` then the logical thing to do is to draw the line over both. Here's an example of drawing on multiple controls: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?531022-Draw-Common-quot-Picture-quot-on-All-Controls

Comment: Ok so there are a couple of possibilities:
1. WinForms: Create buttons and then draw the lines on them
2. WinForms: Make clickable areas of the picture box
3. WPF: Create transparent buttons

I think I'm going to try your solution with drawing on the buttons but thanks for the hint with WPF. Maybe this would be the "cleaner" solution. Are there any other development environments in which you can do this in a "clean" way with VB or java?

Comment: It's not about the development environment. Windows Forms is Windows Forms, whether you create the app in VS or something else. Java uses completely different technology so things would be done differently there. I don't use it so I don't know what the details are.

Comment: Hey, could you please help me and maybe explain the code a little bit? I tried to modify the code so the line is not drawn until a button two is clicked. I wanted to change line 14 to ...ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click but then line 25 won't work

Comment: What is the first private sub there for? I don't see any change when I delete the first private sub. 
I let the code run in single steps an recongnized that if I created 4 buttons the second private sub actually is being loaded 4 times. But why? Every time the sender is the picturebox and every time I'm drawing the same line.

Comment: You're going beyond the scope of this answer to this question. If you have questions about the code I posted elsewhere and linked to here, ask about that code where it's posted.